# Is it possible to open Deft in a sidebar?

Tags: window, window-splitting, deft-mode, side-bar

I'm trying to open Deft in the left sidebar using this code:

```
(setq display-buffer-alist
       '(("*Deft*"
          (display-buffer-in-side-window)
          (window-width . 0.25)
          (side . left)
          (slot . 0))))
```

This is not working and every time I call `M-x deft`, it shows in the main window.

What's wrong with my code? Has anyone had success in running Deft in the sidebar?

Comment: Your regexp doesn't match, try escaping the * it should be like this "\\\*Deft\\\*"

Comment: I tried this before, doesn't change anything. Deft shows in the main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the definition of `deft`  (version 20210101.1519 on MELPA)

```
(defun deft ()
  "Switch to *Deft* buffer and load files."
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer deft-buffer)
  (if (not (eq major-mode 'deft-mode))
      (deft-mode)))
```

So it uses your current window, then switch to a buffer with a name of the value of `deft-buffer` variable, `"\*Deft\*"` by default, then call `deft-mode`. This means that it doesn't create a new window, so setting
`display-buffer-alist` does nothing. (Hope this is clear enough.)

You can probably write this in [function advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html), I prefer to not do this
because of  [reasons](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AdviceVsHooks). So
here is a new function

```
(defun deft-side-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((dummy-buf (generate-new-buffer deft-buffer)))
    (with-current-buffer dummy-buf
      (deft-mode))
    (display-buffer dummy-buf)))
```

Firstly, it creates a new buffer named after the variable `deft-buffer`, call `deft-mode` then having Emacs try to display it, with this, it respects your `display-buffer-alist`.

Here's another version with your window rules if you want to do it manually.

```
(defun deft-side-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((dummy-buf (generate-new-buffer deft-buffer)))
    (with-current-buffer dummy-buf
      (deft-mode))
    (display-buffer-in-side-window dummy-buf
                   '((side . left)
                 (slot . 0)
                 (window-width . 0.25))))))
```

I messed up the formatting but it works! Hope this helps.